# How do I use React props in Typescript correctly?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React and typescript.

I've found I need to declare props as such:

```
const Title = ({title}:{[key:string]:any}) => {
```

But this seems a bit convoluted to me. Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep it simple, if you want, by declaring an interface with all the props you're expecting:

```js
interface MyProps {
  A: string;
  B: number;
  C?: number; // C is optional
}

const MyComponent = ({ A, B }: MyProps) =>  { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the `FC` generic (which is an alias for the `FunctionComponent` generic).  I prefer to use this as apposed to not using the generic because it appends the `children` property as well as types the return value from the functional component, `React.Element` vs `JSX.Element`.

```
import * as React from "react";
import {FC} from "react";

interface ITitleProps {
   title: string;
}

// This works as expected
export const Title1: FC<ITitleProps> = ({
    title,
    children // Added by 'FC'
}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <p>{children}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

// This produces an error
export const Title2 = ({
    title,
    children // property 'children' does not exist on type 'ITitleProps'
}: ITitleProps) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <p>{children}</p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

This GitHub was invaluable trying to figure out how to use TS with React: [React TypeScript Cheatsheet](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet)